# How to insert concatenated columns into a pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data frame that I am transforming into a pivot table I want to add concatenated columns as the values within the pivot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
   
# creating a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Student': ['John', 'Boby', 'Mina', 'Peter', 'Nicky'],
                   
       'Grade': ['Masters', 'Graduate', 'Graduate', 'Masters', 'Graduate'],
       'Major': ['Liberal Arts', 'Business', 'Sciences', 'Education', 'Law'],
        'Age': [27, 23, 21, 23, 24],
        'City': ['Boston', 'Brooklyn', 'Camden', 'Chicago', 'Manhattan'],
        'State': ['MA', 'NY', 'NJ', 'IL', 'NY'],
        'Years' : [2, 4, 3, 3, 4] })
```

**Displays this table**

```
  Student     Grade         Major  Age       City State  Years
0    John   Masters  Liberal Arts   27     Boston    MA      2
1    Boby  Graduate      Business   23   Brooklyn    NY      4
2    Mina  Graduate      Sciences   21     Camden    NJ      3
3   Peter   Masters     Education   23    Chicago    IL      3
4   Nicky  Graduate           Law   24  Manhattan    NY      4
```

**Concatenated Columns**

```
values = pd.concat([df['Age'],df['Years']], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

**Displays this result**

```
    0  1
0  27  2
1  23  4
2  21  3
3  23  3
4  24  4
```

I want to add the concatenated column (values) inside of the pivot table so the table displays the Age and Year in adjacent columns not separate pivot tables

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values =['Age','Years'], index =['Student','City','State'], columns =['Grade', 'Major'], aggfunc = np.sum)

Grade                   Graduate                  Masters             
Major                   Business   Law Sciences Education Liberal Arts
Student City      State                                               
Boby    Brooklyn  NY        23.0   NaN      NaN       NaN          NaN
John    Boston    MA         NaN   NaN      NaN       NaN         27.0
Mina    Camden    NJ         NaN   NaN     21.0       NaN          NaN
Nicky   Manhattan NY         NaN  24.0      NaN       NaN          NaN
Peter   Chicago   IL         NaN   NaN      NaN      23.0          NaN
```

Comment: Do you mean `df.set_index(["Student", "City", "State", "Grade", "Major"]).unstack(["Grade","Major"])`?

Comment: No I want the column header to appear in the pivot above I want to have the age and year as the values next to each other inside the pivot. I want the pivot to look like this

Comment: Business  Education  Law  Liberal Arts  Science 
   Graduate  Masters  Graduate  Masters  Graduate 
Student City State Age Year Age  Year     Age  Year Age    Year   Age Year
Bobby Brooklyn  NY 23 4     0  0          0    0        0    0  0 
John Boston   MA 0 0     0  0          0    0 27    2    0  0
Mina Camden   NJ 0 0     0  0          0    0 0    0   21  3
Nick Manhattan NY 0 0     0  0          24    4 0    0    0  0
Peter Chicago   IL 0 0     23  3          29    0 0    0    0  0